# Date counting in R

Tags: r, date, dplyr, counting

I have a `df` with variables named as below

```
id indexDate eventDate1 eventDate2 V1 V2 V3 ....... V365
```

For the date range `(eventDate1 - indexDate)` to `(eventDate2 - indexDate)`, I want to tag the days of occurrence in the `V1 to V365` columns.

Each `V` represents the number of days post-indexDate.

For example:

If:
`indexDate is 1/1/2017`
`eventDate1 is 1/3/2017 (= Day 2)`
`eventDate2 is 1/5/2017 (= Day 4),`

then:

`V2-V4` would be assigned a value of 1 and the rest of the V~ are 0.

If there is a better way to do this, feel free to let me know!

Thanks.

Comment: For something to be better, it needs to be compared with something else. Can you show what you have tried? Can you provide a reproducible dataset for people to try?

Comment: Perhaps I was not clear but I don't have a solution at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works-

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Make fake data
dates <- data.frame(id = 1:10,
                    indexDate = rep(as.Date("17/01/01"), 10), 
                    eventDate1 = as.Date(paste0("17/01/", 1:10)),
                    eventDate2 = as.Date(paste0("17/01/", 16:25)))

# Step through this to understand what's going on
dates[rep(row.names(dates), 365), ] %>% 
  arrange(id) %>% 
  mutate(Day = rep(1:365, nrow(dates)),
         Flag = ifelse(Day <= as.numeric(eventDate2 - indexDate) & 
                         Day > as.numeric(eventDate1 - indexDate), 1, 0)) %>%
  # move to long format
  spread(Day, Flag)
```

I played with adding a `paste0("V", Day)` but the spread came out unordered. With this column convention you can refer tot he individual columns with back-ticks `.

```
dates %>% select(`1`, `2`, `3`)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Dan!